# pyspark: shingling between different lines in a txt file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce

I need to find all 3-grams shingles in a txt file (sport articles with title and text) in mapreduce way.
However, the txt files have the format

```
This is the title
Content is here on the next line.
This is another line.
```

If I use `sc.textFile()` without processing, `text = sc.textFile().collect()` will be like

```
['This is the title',
 '',
 'Content is here on the next line.',
 '',
 'This is another line.']
```

because of that the text file have multiple lines.
As a result, 3-grams shingling will be like

```
[['This is the',
  'is the title'],
 [],
 ['Content is here', 
  'is here on',
  'here on the',
  'here on the',
  'the next line.'],
 [],
 ['This is another',
  'is another line.']]
```

if I use the map function `text.map(shingling)`

```
k = 3
def shingling(text):
    tokens = text.split()
    shingle = [' '.join(tokens[i:i+k])
                     for i in range(len(tokens) - k + 1)]
    return shingle
```

What I want is like

```
['This is the',
 'is the title',
 'the title Content',
 'title Content is',
 ......]
```

and I want to know if there is any function to use or how I should modify my code in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to combine the lines using the code below:

```
rdd = sc.textFile('text')

rdd2 = sc.parallelize([rdd.fold('', lambda x, y: x + ' ' + y)]).map(shingling)

>>> rdd2.collect()
[['This is the', 'is the title', 'the title Content', 'title Content is',
  'Content is here', 'is here on', 'here on the', 'on the next', 'the next line.',
  'next line. This', 'line. This is', 'This is another', 'is another line.']]
```